# Create a watcher for a object that does not exist yet

Tags: javascript, promise

I am working on a feature that I need to track an asynchronous request inside a synchronous one. Let me explain

I have a bit of code the looks something like this

```js
const myObj = {};

function sendMessage(requestId, data) {
  kafkaProducer("requestTopic", {requestId, ...data});
  
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Here is the problem
    const dataINeed = myObj[requestId];
    // This object is meant to be only temporary
    delete myObj[requestId];

    resolve(dataINeed);
  })
}

kafkaConsumer("callbackTopic", (response) => {
  myObj[response.requestId] = response.data;
}
```

I know the code above does not work, and this is the issue. I need to `resolve()` that `Promise` only when the consumer actualy creates the object (or on timeout).

I can´t just attach the Promise to the consumer, because, if I send more than one request at the same time, each request needs their own data and not the data that responds first.

Also, I could create a new consumer with a new topic just for that request and, when it consumes, I shut down the consumer and delete the topic to not overload my kafka cluster with a bunch of ghost topics and partitions. But I don´t know if this is a good ideia.

**Why do I need that?**

This is suposed to replace database requests. The ideia is have a DB as a Service, but keep a similar structure to which the APIs are using it (mongoose)

Comment: What is `callbackTopic`?

Comment: Is not clear what you're asking (at least not to me) but a dirty approach will be to store the `resolve` function of the `Promise` as a global variable and call it inside the callback function that you pass to `kafkaConsumer`.

Comment: "*This is suposed to replace database requests*" - not sure what problem you are trying to solve by putting a kafka queue between your application and your database, but this doesn't sound right.

Comment: @trincot callbackTopic is just a string

Answer (score 2):

Store the `resolve` functions in your map, not the result objects:

```
const myObj = {};

function sendMessage(requestId, data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    myObj[requestId] = resolve;
    kafkaProducer(requestTopic, {requestId, ...data});
  })
}

kafkaConsumer(callbackTopic, ({requestId, data}) => {
  const resolve = myObj[requestId];
  if (!resolve) throw new Error(`Got response for ${requestId} but request does not exist`);
  delete myObj[requestId];
  resolve(data);
});
```